# Git workflow: submitting pull requests to upstream and using the commits in the meantime

Tags: git, github, version-control, pull-request

I've just started working with Git and I'm trying to figure out the best workflow for maintaining a forked repository and committing changes upstream via pull requests on Github.

I've been reading for a while, but haven't figure out the best practice. Let's use this one specific example, but this is a general workflow question.

Similar to the suggestion at [Git workflow: forking a project and maintaing a local modified copy, but keep up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386352/git-workflow-forking-a-project-and-maintaing-a-local-modified-copy-but-keep-up), I've created a fork of magiclabs/alchemy_cms (upstream), off the 3.0-stable branch and then created another branch based off 3.0-stable to hold all custom changes. Let's call that branch custom.

Now the question is, when I want to make a new change and commit it back to the upstream magiclabs/alchemy_cms repo, what's the best way to do that so that I can create a pull request to merge to master AND also start to use that commit in the custom branch immediately. The PR may not be merged immediately, might needs changes, or might not be accepted.

What I've been doing is creating a feature branch off of master in the forked repo to get a clean pull request to submit upstream. Once I submit the pull request, I `git cherry-pick` that commit to get it into the custom branch.

This seems unclean since it creates a duplicate commit hash and I'm not sure what will happen when the pull request is accepted.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not just create a new feature branch off of your other feature branch? You can always rebase or cherry-pick commits to other branches later if you need to.

Comment: If I do that, I won't be able to submit a clean pull request on GitHub, right? The reason I was making a branch off of master was so that I could submit a clean pull request upstream. The combination of contributing upstream and getting the same commit onto our branch is what I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I've been doing [to contribute to upstream] is creating a feature branch off of master in the forked repo to get a clean pull request to submit upstream. Once I submit the pull request, I git cherry-pick that commit to get it into the custom branch.

This is the correct way to do this. I manage projects on "custom" branches this way. When you periodically merge the upstream branch, it'll have 2 commits for the same operation... no big deal.

If your PR had to be reworked and no longer matches, you'll have a conflict at merge time, but that's an unavoidable cost of sailing ahead in a direction unapproved by the project leaders.